# 17-18 year old rules

Tags: united-states

Hello everyone I am in California for a trip and as a foreigner I noticed that there are restrictions (ex: curfew) that prevent me from fully enjoying my trip, I have 17 at the moment because I was born at the end of the year but the problem is when I will reach my 18 years I will not have enough time to enjoy the rest of my trip because I will have 8 or 9 days left before leaving.

So I wanted to know if there was an exception for people who are almost 18 years old?

Comment: I don't believe California actually has a curfew, though some cities/counties might. The answer will depend on exactly where in the state you are. Generally speaking, though, the law is probably going to apply to people under age *x*, and there won't be exceptions for people who are almost *x*, as that would just mean the law actually applies to people under the age of *x-y*, raising the question of whether the people who are almost *x-y* should be subject to the law, thus making the law actually apply to people who are *x-y-z*, and so on.

Comment: Is somebody in the group at least 18? Often, you just need a note from your parents designating them your guardian. See [San Jose's ordinance](https://library.municode.com/ca/san_jose/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=TIT10PUPEMOWE_CH10.28YOPRCUOR), for example.

Answer (score 1):

### You are 18 or you are not

If there are things you can do when you turn 18, you can't do them at 17 years 354 days.

For example, where I live in [australia](/questions/tagged/australia) you can vote and drink on your 18th birthday and not one day before.